# jqgrid - predefined formatter actions - change the default action of edit selected row button

Tags: jqgrid

Can we change the default action of the "edit selected row" button?

Here is my code for the grid

```
jQuery("#detFlex62_1").jqGrid({
    url: root + mod + '/detaillistview', 
    datatype: "clientSide", 
    colNames:[' ', '<?=lang("users_company_code")?>', '<?=lang("users_company_name")?>', ' ', ' '], 
    colModel:[ 
        {name:'myac', width:50, fixed:true, sortable:false, resize:false, formatter:'actions', formatoptions:{keys:true,delOptions: {reloadAfterSubmit:false},editOptions: {reloadAfterSubmit:false}}},
        {name:'company_code',index:'company_code', width:100}, 
        {name:'company_name',index:'company_name', width:100}, 
        {name:'company_id',index:'company_id', width:100,hidden:true}, 
        {name:'company_access_id',index:'company_access_id', width:100,hidden:true} 
        ], 
    width: $('.body').width()-40, 
    height: 120, 
    pager: '#pagerFlex62_1', 
    sortname: 'user_id', 
    sortorder: "desc", 
    editurl: root + mod + '/detailpost',
    caption:"<?=lang("users_title")?>", 
    onSelectRow: function(id){ 
        activedf = "#detFlex62_1";
    }
}); 

jQuery("#detFlex62_1").jqGrid('navGrid','#pagerFlex62_1',{edit:false,del:false,search:false, addfunc: df_add_1});
```

I know I should put something in the editOptions part of the code. Right now I only put reloadAfterSubmit:false. What is the option to execute our own custom function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need just calling custom function when you press 'Edit' button in navigation bar, your navgrid should look like this:

```
jQuery("#detFlex62_1").jqGrid('navGrid', "#mainGridNavi", { edit: true, add: false, del: false, editfunc: function() { alert('test'); }})
```

Regards.